# Can I save chart as image without toolbox interaction in Echarts?

Tags: echarts

I'd like to save an echart as an image. If the `toolbox.saveAsImage` option is set to `true`, I can use a toolbox action to save the chart. However, I'm wondering if this can be done programmatically?

Comment: According to the echarts 2.0 documentation there is an `option` parameter called `renderAsImage` which is a boolean (true|false). I think it renders the chart as an image instead of a canvas chart. Unfortunately, this parameter is completely gone from the echarts 3.0 documentation which tells me that it wasn't used as much, but I would still experiment around with version 2 and see what this can do and if supports a callback function which could enable saving the image to a path.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should be achieved by `echartsInstance.getDataURL`, with which you can set image format, pixel ratio and so on.

```
(opts: {
    // Exporting format, can be either png, or jpeg
    type?: string,
    // Resolution ratio of exporting image, 1 by default.
    pixelRatio?: number,
    // Background color of exporting image, use backgroundColor in option by default.
    backgroundColor?: string,
    // Excluded components list. e.g. ['toolbox']
    excludeComponents?: Array.<string>
}) => string
```

See [ECharts doc](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.getDataURL) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

If you have echart instance variable, use `getDataURL` method with params like this:

```
echartInstance.getDataURL({
    pixelRatio: 2,
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
});
```

Calling `e.getDataURL()` without options won't work.